# How to interpret multinomial logistic regression results in r with ordered independent variable?

Tags: ordinal-data, multinomial-distribution, independence

If there is a independent variable X that is a ordered factor (low, medium, high) - high being the base class, the results of the multinomial regression for each class in X should be interpreted as follows? "Moving from low to high category changes the log of odds of the Y dependent variable by the beta in the equation".